# Decreasing space between navbar links

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to decrease the space between the links in my collapsed nav-bar. Could someone help me out please? I've looked around a fair bit, but I don't think I'm searching for the right thing.
[Here is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6AHB.jpg) and as you can see, the space between the 'links' is very big. How can I make it shorter please?

Thanks in advance!

Here is my code:
CSS:

```
.navbar-header {
        background-color: #ffffff;

}

.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
    color: #666699;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-collapse, .navbar-default .navbar-form {
     background-color: #ffffff;

}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
    background-color: #666699;
}

.navbar-brand,
.navbar-nav li a {
    line-height: 85px;
    height: 85px;
    padding-top: 0;
}

.navbar-toggle, span {
    line-height: 75px;
    height: 70px;
    padding-top: 0px;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
    color: #666699;
}

.sitecolor {
    background-color: #666699;
}

.img-thumbnail {
    line-height: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    padding-top: 0px ;
    border-color: transparent;
}

#navbar-logo {
    line-height: 30px !important;
    height: 86px !important;
    padding-top: 2px !important;
}

.nav>li>a {
    padding: 9px 20px !important;
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="sitecolor">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Title</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
      <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
     <link type = "text/css" href="css/stylesheet.css"   rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body class="sitecolor">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <!--<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">BSWeb</a> -->
        <a href="#">
            <img id="navbar-logo" src="http://www.betches.com/sites/default/files/article/list/images/google.jpg" />
        </a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
  <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

At the bottom of my CSS, I've tried .nav>li>a but not sure that has helped.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. It would be helpful if you would post some code to show what you have tried

Answer (score 0):

This could help (at least that's what comes to my mind without your code):

```
.navbar-nav li {
margin-bottom: 0; /* play with this value */
margin-top: 0; /* an this too */
}
```

Comment: This resolves it, but only on mobile devices. When I make the browser bigger, it compacts it all into the top right corner

Answer (score 0):

```
.nav li{
    margin-top: 10px; //change the 10 if you want
}
```

what you tried at the bottom of your CSS involves the padding.. you're looking for margins between elements.. specifically in this case the `<li>` elements

but if you like the position that the first Link is in and you just want to make the bottom 3 Links become closer to the top and each other then you're going to have to give the last 3 `<li>` elements a class name such as:

```
<li class="margin"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
<li class="margin"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
<li class="margin"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
```

then in your CSS:

```
.margin{
    margin-top: 10px; //again, you can edit this
}
```

Comment: This works, but only on small browsers where the page is smaller.

Comment: what do you mean 'small browsers'? like, small monitors? or minimized screens?

Comment: Yes minimised screens, when I drag to make it smaller and the links go into the button it works fine; however when I drag the screen out and have it at full size the links compact into the top right

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap those rules in a media query so they won't apply to your mobile navigation links:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li {
    padding: 35px 10px;
  }
}
```

Sidenote: You don't (or shouldn't need to use the !important declaration). See revised CSS.

Working Example Snippet at FullPage.

```css
.navbar.navbar-default {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 0;
}
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-collapse,
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-form {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  background-color: #666699;
}
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-header .navbar-toggle {
  padding: 40px 15px;
}
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: #666699;
}
.sitecolor {
  background-color: #666699;
}
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
  color: #666699;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  padding-top: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-brand img {
  height: 80px;
  margin: 20px 0px 0px;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li {
    padding: 35px 10px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<body class="sitecolor">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <!--<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">BSWeb</a> -->
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
          <img src="http://www.betches.com/sites/default/files/article/list/images/google.jpg" />
        </a>
      </div>

      <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
  </nav>
```